php redis module and php compile mismatch
I am trying to install php-redis via pecl.
Running this:
php -i | grep API

gives this: PHP API => 20220829
I then run pecl install redis and I get the message:
...
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20220829
Zend Module Api No:      20220829
Zend Extension Api No:   420220829
...
Build process completed successfully
Installing '/usr/lib/php/20230831/redis.so'
install ok: channel://pecl.php.net/redis-6.0.2
Extension redis enabled in php.ini

As you can see, there is a mismatch between the apis.
When I inspect php with php -i | grep redis, I get this error message:
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: redis: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20230831
PHP    compiled with module API=20220829
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0

I am on php8.2, so api 20220829 is correct.
My question is, how can I install redis for api 20220829 to match my php version.

Do you have more than one version of PHP installed?

And why do you use pecl to install php-redis? Why not apt install php-redis? If you use your package repositories you're guaranteed that versions will match and that this stays true after upgrades.

@vidarlo installing with apt gives the same error. I must have different versions of php installed i.e. php8.3

What does whereis pecl and whereis php output? [Edit] your question to include this.

@Paul yes, that was it, I posted an answer, thanks.

@vidarlo - pecl: /usr/bin/pecl /usr/share/man/man1/pecl.1.gz and php: /usr/bin/php8.2 /usr/bin/php /usr/bin/php8.3. This means I had multiple versions of php so I switched (I posted an answer about it)

The issue was I had more than one version of php on my system which I could see with php-config.
I ran this to make my system switch to php8.2:
sudo -- sh -c "for P in php php-config phpize phar phar.phar; do update-alternatives --set \$P /usr/bin/\${P}8.1; done"
